# How to hide Html.ActionLink from _Layout page to another cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to mvc. For now I am trying to make a Login page. If login is successful, then it should redirect to the admin page. That works perfectly but it shows the `Login` button even though the login was successful. I want only the `logout` button in the admin view after login is successful.

For now my admin view shows something like this:

> **Login** **Logout**
>   **Welcome Admin**

but I want something like this

> **Logout**
>   **Welcome Admin**

Here is my
_Layout.cshtml page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "MyAccount")</li>
    <li>
    @{
      if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "MyAccount")</li>
      }                          
    }
    </li>
</ul>
```

And Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Login l, string returnUrl = "")
{
    //Some code//
    {
                return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Home");
    }
}
```

And Admin view:

```
<h2>
    Welcome @(Request.IsAuthenticated ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name: "")
</h2>
```

I don't know whether this is possible or not to hide Login button from the _layout to the admin view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not render the links conditionally using `if-else` ?

```
<ul>
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "MyAccount")</li>
}
else 
{    
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "MyAccount")</li>
}
</ul>
```